# Read json returned by 400 error clojure

Tags: json, clojure, openurl, http-status-code-400

I have a web-service that reply at some get request, something like this:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/reviews?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&id=ARH6W4X1187B99274F&format=json&results=1&start=2
if a parameter in the request is wrong:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/reviews?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&id=ARH6W4X1187B99274F&format=json&results=1&start=WRONG-STRING
the server reply with a 400 and some json explain what is went wrong.

Now in clojure I want to read the json to know exactly what is went wrong, i tried with 
(clojure.java.io/reader wrong-url)
but it thrown an exception

> Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/reviews?
>   api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&id=ARH6W4X1187B99274F&format=json&results=1&start=e1
>   [Thrown class java.io.IOException]

How can i read the json ?

Comment: My big problem is that clojure.java.io/reader thrown an exception because it get the 400 error, but after that (i assume) i get the json that i need... The problem is not parse the json is **get** the json after the 400

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just *really* want to see what's going over the wire, and in those situations I fire up  [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), a network packet analyser. Here's how I'd use it in this case (but it's a powerful and flexible piece of software, you can do lots of nifty stuff with it):

1. Start it up
2. select Capture->Options (Ctrl-K)
3. select the network interface you want to capture traffic for
4. enter `host developer.echonest.com` as the capture filter
5. hit the *start capture* button

Then interact with your service at echonest.com - you'll see packets coming in in Wireshark's window. When you're done, go back to Wireshark and hit Capture->Stop (Ctrl-E).

In the list of packets, find the one that starts with `GET /api/v4/arist/`..., right-click and select "Follow TCP Stream" — That will show you exactly what is being sent and received.